# C++ Inheritance: Calling Parent Class Constructor

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I'm hitting my head against the wall trying to remember how to deal with inheritance. Lets say we have a parent/base class called Fruits and child/derived class called Apples. Apples is only different from Fruits in that it has one extra variable, called number. How would we implement it so that Apples by default always calls the parent class constructor, with the values "Apples" (the name) and SNACK (the type)?

Fruits would be implemented as such (

```
Fruits::Fruits(string name, KIND type): myName(name), myKind(type)
{}
```

How would Apples be implemented, so that if Apples is called as Apples() it defaults name to "Apples" and type to SNACK, with number to 5?
Is this correct?

```
Apples::Apples() : Fruits("Apple", SNACK)
{
    number = 5;
}
 Apples::Apples(int num)  : FoodItem("Pancakes", BREAKFAST )
{

}
```

Comment: You talk about apples and fruits, but what I see is Pancake and FoodItem. Would you mind straighting up your example?

Comment: What's the relation between `Fruit` and `FoodItem`?

Comment: @Arun edit...made a mistake!

Comment: @ohbrobig: Thanks, that explains. I have added an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This way is correct:

```
Apples::Apples() : Fruits("Apple", BREAKFAST)
{
    number = 5;
}
```

but this way would be better as it more readable and consistent:

```
Apples::Apples() : Fruits("Apple", BREAKFAST), number( 5 )
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try these:

```
// Default value for number
Apples::Apples() : Fruits("Apple", SNACK), number(5)
{
}

// Caller specified value for number
Apples::Apples(int num)  : FoodItem("Pancakes", BREAKFAST), number(num)
{
}
```